# React text splitting with html generation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My input is

```
const text = 'Hello @kevin12 How are you?'
```

How I render it

```
<span>{text}</span>
```

How I want to render it

```
<span>Hello <em>@kevin12</em> How are you?</span>
```

My parsing function (incomplete)

```
const parseText = value => {
  const mention = value.substring(value.lastIndexOf('@')+1)
  const words = value.split(mention)
  return words.map(word => word === mention ? React.createElement('em', {}, word) : word)
}
```

...

```
<span>{parseText(text)}</span>
```

Please help me complete this rendering function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by words, iterate over the array and find the item that start with `@`

```
export default function App() {
  const text = "Hello @kevin12 How are you?";
  const parseText = value => {
    const mention = value.split(" ");
    return mention.map(w => (w[0] === "@" ? <em> {w} </em> : <> {w}</>));
  };
  return (
    <span>
      <span>{parseText(text)}</span>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const parseText = value => {
    const words = value.split(' ')
    return words.map((word, index) => {
      if (index !== words.length - 1) {
        word += " "
      }
      return word[0] === '@' ? <em>{word}</em> : word;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest going through the regex, here is the sample code

```
    const text = 'Hello @kevin12 How are you?';
    let finalResult = test;
    let re =/(?:^|\W)@(\w+)(?!\w)/g;
    let match,matches =[];
   while(match =re.exec(test)){
     let found ='@'+match[1];
     let replace ='<em>'+found+'</em>';
     finalresult =finalResult.replace(found,replace);
   }
 console.log(finalResult) ;
```